# Assigning Content of a Variable to a Pointer Not Working in C and proC

Tags: c, pointers

I am having the following problem in my C code on a UNIX Platform.

```
 function1(short *a)
 {
    EXEC SQL begin declare section;
          short a1;
    EXEC SQL end declare section;

    EXEC SQL fetch quey_cursor
     into
          :a1;

    // More processing

    *a = a1;

 }
```

The problem is the program is exiting at this line

```
  *a = a1;
```

and I am not able to get debugs.

I really appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: this is how it's done:
function()
{
  short *a;

  function1(a);
}

Comment: Should be function1(&a).

Comment: Be very carefull with this. Probably the most common mistake. As you learned, hard to track. If  your function call requires a pointer (call by reference), don't pass a scalar (call by value).

Comment: You should improve your function names.  Any thing like  some-word() is going to be seen by the reader as a function.  Saying function() is redundant and dosn't communicate what the function does.

Comment: actually i only named it this way to explain, I don't use this convention. Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you are not allocating memory for the pointer. So, when you try to dereference it as `*a=a1`, it's crashing. Since, it's only a single pointer, you can simply declare and use it as:

```
function() { 
   short a; 
   function1(&a);
}
```

Notice the difference with declaration and argument passed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass to function1() a valid pointer to a short for the assignment to *a to work. The error is in where function1() was called.